# Qt- Pop up notification using JNI

Tags: java, android, qt, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I trying to create pop up notification when new messages received. 
Firstly , I want to create simple dialog in Java and test it.

**Text.java:**

```
public static void popUpDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

      // set title
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
      // create alert dialog
      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

      // show it
       alertDialog.show();

}
```

And show it when messages arrived through JNI.

**Text.cpp:**

```
            mid = m_env->GetStaticMethodID(g_clazz, "popUpDialog", "()V");

            if (messageType == TextMessage)
                m_env->CallStaticVoidMethod(g_clazz, mid, jsReceivedMessage);
            else
            {
                jstring jsPreparedMessage = m_env->NewStringUTF(messageTypeStr(messageType).c_str());

                m_env->CallStaticVoidMethod(g_clazz, mid, jsPreparedMessage);
                m_env->DeleteLocalRef(jsPreparedMessage);
            }
```

Actually , my Application have crash when messages receive. How to use it?

Comment: _"Actually , my Application have crash when messages receive. "_ Then you should include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: One thing that looks strange is that you're trying to pass a string to `popUpDialog`, even though that method doesn't take any arguments.